# How to debug backwards in PyCharm?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

We all know <kbd>F9</kbd> goes forward in debug mode. But how can we go backward after going a couple steps forward with <kbd>F9</kbd> or is that even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how can we go backward after going a couple steps forward with F9 or **is that possible?**

It isn't possible, you can't *"go back"* during debugging. (That is the case in Python and other programming languages/debuggers in general.)

The reason is the debugger would have to restore the state of your program to the previous step. Which using your logic would involve holding a copy of the entire state (memory, stack, temporary files, etc...) at every step of the program. (Not to mention operations protocols that aren't reversible and require precise timing.) That would be exponential and become easily unfeasible. That's why it's not done.

Comment: It is not true that this is impossible! GDB can do reverse execution on some widely used targets including x86. Then there is ocanldebug... these are two on which I have used the feature. There might be others.

Comment: @Marko the question isn't about GDB but the default PyCharm debugger, using alternative debuggers on PyCharm is it's own issue and as the question asked there won't be a "go backwards" button in the GUI. Instead of laying broad claims in the comments you can go ahead and write your own post with a proof-of-concept. And as I said, the GDB's "go back" functionality won't work when you have a non-reversible state.

Comment: @bad_coder https://github.com/airportyh/time-traveling-debugger/issues https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=HlndMuAguEk

Comment: @Gintas_ very interesting links, but there's a limited demand for those advanced functionalities. Most applications don't require those kinds of debuggers and as even popular debugger's like PyCharm's have bugs I wonder how reliable and productive those experimental debuggers will be... But I like the concept, hopefully we'll get to see more of those functionalities become commonplace.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is not correct. You can step back, the state of the program doesn't have to be rewinded. The interpretation where you would rewind the state falls apart when you are in any sort of loop, recursion or function call as it's not clear which state you want to rewind to.

Stepping back is useful when you don't want to restart the whole application to check the code in question. In that case you step back to the last fresh state or just keep in mind that some variables have changed.

As of 2024 this feature is not implemented in PyCharm, however it is present in many other editors, like VS, VSCode, Rider.

[PyCharm Moving debugging cursor backward](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-58276/Moving-debugging-cursor-backward)